# How to make Dropsdownlist + text inline under 768px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my dropdownlists I have created to be on the same line under `768px`.
Right now, I'm using the `form-inline`, but that only works over `768px` and not under.

Can any tell me how this can be done? Have tried with a list, but that did not work well.
As you can see in the fiddle, I want some text over each dropdownlist. I know i'm not using an label, cause this makes

[My Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixeldk/f8gfa768/)

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        Adult<br />
        <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-adult">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        Child (3-15)<br />
        <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-child">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        Infant (0-3)<br />
        <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-infant">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        Pet<br />
        <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-pet">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">

    <div class="padding-top15">
        <button type="submit" class="bookingbutton">BOOK NOW</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can tell me what I should look at.

**Updated:**

I think you guys have misunderstood what I was trying to tell. Right now when viewing the page **over 768px** the dropdownlists are inline as they should be. 
If the webpage goes under 768px, all the dropdownlists going out of the inline, which it should not do. I just want to use 2 lines instead of 5-8

I just want it to look the same as it does over 768px. I have uploaded the image of how it should look like under 768px.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Bootstrap add classes to make a responsive grid. If you want your lists to be always on the same line just add this in you css:

```
.form-group{
  display:inline-block
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f8gfa768/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to achieve under `768px width`:

```
[text] [dropdown] <!-- new line -->
[text] [dropdown] <!-- new line -->
[text] [dropdown] <!-- new line -->
[text] [dropdown] <!-- new line -->
```

---

Those `br` tags are messing up your styles. Why don't you remove them, and add `display: block/inline-block` styles to `select` element, depending on the *window width*, which will replace that `br`:

```
select{
    display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    select{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

---

```css
#Dropdown-adult {
     height: 30px;
     font-size: 15px;
     width: 45px;
}

#Dropdown-child {
     height: 30px;
     font-size: 15px;
     width: 80px;
}

#Dropdown-infant {
     height: 30px;
     font-size: 15px;
     width: 80px;
}

#Dropdown-pet {
     height: 30px;
     font-size: 15px;
     width: 45px;
}

#Dropdown-vehicles {
     max-width: 100%; 
     height: 30px;
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 15px;
}

.bookingbutton {
    background-color: #F6861F;
    border-style: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 110px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
}

.padding-top15 {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

select{
    display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    select{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            Adult
            <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-adult">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            Child (3-15)
            <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-child">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            Infant (0-3)
            <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-infant">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            Pet
            <select class="dropdown" id="Dropdown-pet">
                <option>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        
        <div class="padding-top15">
            <button type="submit" class="bookingbutton">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8gfa768/2/)